# Passing variable that may contain a wildcard as an argument

Tags: shell, awk, sed, while-loop, grep

I'm doing a comparison between two variables, variable1 and variable2. If there are duplicates between the two variables, I want to **remove the whole line in the variable** in which the duplicate appears in variable1.

For example:

```
variable1
-----
aaa* 
bbb
ccc*
ddd

variable2
-----
aaa* 
bbb
```

My expected output is:

```
variable1
-----
ccc*
ddd
```

The output that I am currently getting:

```
variable1
------
aaa*
ccc*
ddd
```

This is my script:

```
echo "$variable2" | sed "/"$variable1"/d" >> output.txt
```

Why is my variable1 argument not capturing the wildcard at the end of the string?

Comment: Count the quotes in `sed "/"$variable1"/d"`. For each one ask yourself - is the text that follows inside or outside of quotes? What would you **want** the answer to be for `$variable1`?

Answer (score 0):

letting your variables be in their own files

```
$ cat var1.txt 
aaa*
bbb
ccc*
ddd

$ cat var2.txt 
aaa*
bbb
```

you can use the `comm` (common)  command to isolate what two files do or do not have in common.

```
$ comm -23 var1.txt var2.txt 
ccc*
ddd
```

The flag -23 says to not print the second or third output columns
where the

- first column is rows unique to the first file
- second column is rows unique to the second file
- third column is rows common to both files

Both files must be sorted or `comm` will complain.